# How can I create an appmenu/DBusmenu using python?

Tags: python, application-development, appmenu, dbus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add support for the global menu to a python non-gtk, non-qt app?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98692/how-to-add-support-for-the-global-menu-to-a-python-non-gtk-non-qt-app)

I want to add support for the indicator-appmenu to an application that is not written in one of the supported toolkits. I want to use a python script as a bridge and I would like to know how I attach the menu structure to the appmenu (or to do the communication between application and appmenu).

I found and read the following resources:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/LauncherAPI#Python_Example
  This explains very well how to create a Dbusmenu, however they attach it to the quicklist of the launcher. I would expect a similar way to attach it to the appmenu?
- wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationMenu
  no documentation available yet (?)
- http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-11.10/python/Dbusmenu-0.4.html
  I don't understand how this looks in a script, I would need an example. Can someone tell me a python application that adds an appmenu on its own (where the appmenu is not extracted automatically from the toolkit)?

Comment: Define for the sake of the question what you consider an "appmenu".

Comment: The "global menu" is often called "appmenu". And from the question this is also pretty clear. The only two supported toolkits are gtk and qt and both implementations are completely undeocumented. And yes, this question is a duplicate of my question.